# How to change the path of file to be saved?

Tags: php, file, export

I need to change the path of the file to be saved. Please help me.

```
$filename = "All Reports";
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename . ".xls");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Comment: Change `$filename` to what you want. What's the problem?

Comment: This will just tell the browser to download the file. It's up to the user to decide where it should be saved.

Comment: Do you mean you need to save it into a different folder on the user's computer? The server can't do that.

Comment: Please give me example. When I add the file path to the filename, it only includes to the filename.

Comment: The folder that's used is controlled by how the user sets their download preferences in the browser. There's nothing you can do to override it.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know how to get the download path by code in php?

Comment: How can I upload the exported file automatically after the update?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell the browser which directory (path) to use in order to save the file.

If you could do that it means that you have access to the user's data and its a security risk.